# Laravel 5.2 League CSV output adding extra line with numbers at the end

Tags: csv, laravel-5

I am creating a very simple CSV file for download in Laravel 5.2.  I am on a Mac.  I have installed the League/CVS Library with composer and created this simple function:

```
public function createCSVDemo()
{
    $header = ["Dates" , "Times"];
    $contents = [
        [date('Y-m-d'), date('H:i')],
        [date('Y-m-d'), date('H:i')],
    ];
    $csv = Writer::createFromFileObject(new \SplTempFileObject()); 
    $csv->insertOne($header);
    $csv->insertAll($contents);

    return $csv->output('demo.csv');
}
```

The function returns the data but there is always an extra line at the end with numbers.

```
Dates   Times
2016-08-26  14:29
2016-08-26  14:29
139
```

I have tried adding the lines listed below.  These change the number but they do not remove it.

```
$cvs->setDelimiter("\t");
$cvs->setNewline("\r\n"); 
$cvs->setOutputBOM(Writer::BOM_UTF8);
```

Can someone tell me what the number is and what I need to do to properly handle it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numbers are being written to the last line because you are returning `$csv->output('demo.csv')`

This needs to be executed first, then `return` or `die()` afterwards.

E.g.

```
$csv->output('demo.csv');
return;
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was exactly what I needed.